# Using Logic monad to backtrack upon exception thrown with ExceptT

Tags: haskell, search, alternative-functor, monadplus

I'd like to use the `Logic` monad to ensure that error-throwing code (in a monad stack including `ExcepT`) backtracks upon throwing an error. Here's a simple example:

```
newtype FooT m a = FooT { unFooT :: ExceptT String m a }
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadTrans, MonadError String, MonadFail)
 

foo :: FooT Logic String
foo = do
  let validate s = if s == "cf" then return s else throwError "err"
  let go = do
        first <- msum (map return ['a', 'b', 'c'])     
        second <- msum (map return ['d', 'e', 'f'])
        traceM $ "Guess: " ++ [first, second]
        validate [first, second]
  go `catchError` const mzero

testfoo :: IO ()
testfoo = do
  let r = observe $ runExceptT $ unFooT foo
  case r of
    Left e -> print $ "Error: " ++ e
    Right s -> print $ "Result: " ++
```

This doesn't backtrack; it produces no results.
I can make it backtrack by lifting the choice operations (ie, use `lift (msum ...)` instead of the plain `msum` call there is now).
However, for a variety of reasons I'd like to be able to write code in the `ExceptT` monad and basically just lift the `MonadPlus` instance from the Logic monad into the transformed version.
I tried to write a custom `MonadPlus` instance to accomplish this here:

```
instance MonadPlus m => MonadPlus (FooT m) where
  mzero = lift mzero
  mplus (FooT a) (FooT b) = lift $ do
    ea <- runExceptT a
    case ea of
      Left _ -> do
        eb <- runExceptT b
        case eb of
          Left _ -> mzero
          Right y -> return y
      Right x -> do
        eb <- runExceptT b
        case eb of
          Left _ -> return x
          Right y -> return x `mplus` return y
```

The same code works for the `Alternative` instance as well. However, this doesn't actually help; it still doesn't backtrack. Is there something wrong with this instance? Is there a better way to solve this problem? Am I trying to do something that doesn't make sense? At the end of the day I can always just lift everything, but would prefer to avoid doing so.

Edit:
Have been messing around some more. My `MonadPlus` instance above works if I use `mplus` but does *not* work if I use `msum` like I did above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instance of `MonadPlus`/`Alternative`:

```hs
instance (Alternative m, Monad m) => Alternative (FooT m) where
  empty = FooT (ExceptT empty)
  FooT (ExceptT a) <|> FooT (ExceptT b) = FooT (ExceptT (a <|> b))
```

Note: `Alternative` and `MonadPlus` are redundant, so it's simpler to just implement `Alternative`, and use `Data.Foldable.asum` instead of `msum`.

The one you implemented is not too different from the one that's already on `ExceptT`, and does not really use the `Alternative m` instance. Make sure to use `(<|>)` specialized to `m` to benefit from backtracking.